# How to trigger 'beforeunload' event from within an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, dom-events, iframe-app

I have an application (name it B) which is being embbeded in an Iframe by another main application (Name it A or parent).

```
So: App A--                     // domain of A: https://mydomain/mainApp
           |___ App B in Iframe // domain in B: https://mydomain/appB
```

**Problem is**: Then main/parent app has a navigation menu. One item, when clicked, creates an Iframe with SRC ATTRIBUTE loading App B inside.

When the user clicks into another option of the menu in app A, the Iframe is destroyed and another content View in React appears, replacing the Iframe.

When doing this, all data typed in forms by the user in B are gone, as I can not trigger a save event I have in B.

I have added following event handler in the iframe app:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

    // Trigger here the save settigns event inside B
});
```

But former **code is never triggering** when user navigates through Main App menu. As I can see, navigating menu in App A, changes URL in the browser(but seems a SPA React.js routing or similar, no real redirection).

**Question is**: Can Iframe detect when is going to be unloaded/destroyed to trigger first the Saving Settings in Ajax ? P.S: I don't have access to App A code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> The `WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload` event handler property contains the code executed when the `beforeunload` is sent. This event fires when a window is about to `unload` its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

> The `unload` event is fired when the document or a child resource is
> being unloaded. It is fired after:
>
> 1. `beforeunload` (cancellable event)
> 2. `pagehide`

Example:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="removeIframeBtn" value="remove iframe"/>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://localhost:8080/iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>

<script>
    const removeIframeBtn = document.getElementById("removeIframeBtn");
    const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

    iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
        debugger;
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        debugger;
    };

    removeIframeBtn.onclick = function () {
        iframe.remove();
    };
</script>
```

Let assume that page with current code is opened in the browser tab.

If you try to close this tab, `iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload` will be called.

If you try to click on `remove iframe` btn, `iframe` will be removed from document but `iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload` will not call. There is no `unload` event.

React renders components with js, so it is totally like second case with clicking on `remove iframe` btn.

So the answer on your question is: it is not possible to detect unloading of iframe with `onbeforeunload` event in single page application on route changing.

Solution for you can be to save settings on every its change.

Answer (score 0):

The `unload` event works so you can do:

```js
iframeWindow.addEventListener('unload', () => {
  debugger;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### August 2023:

The `unload` (and `pagehide`) is triggered when an `iframe` is deleted by its parent. Add an `unload` event listener within the iframe, and it will fire. **However**, as of August 2023, there seems to be a bug in Firefox which causes `unload` (and `pagehide`) to not fire, so I can only confirm that this works in Chrome as of writing (I haven't tested Safari - someone with a Mac please comment).